# How to convert Time duration in Top command for analysis in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I am currently running a small script through SAS to analyze Top command data using the default layout of top in Linux. The data is currently being transferred into an MSSQL DB. Before you ask, the SAS language does a great job of handling the variation in spaces which can be very challenging from line to line in the "top" result.

What I need to do is convert the process duration column into a data type that I can perform aggregate functions (e.g. average, min, max). The value appears by default as (emphasizing with bold type):

```
ID   COMMAND      %CPU **TIME**     #TH   #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP PPID
1532  processX     0.0  **00:00.04** 5     3    46    2868K  0B     0B     1532 1
...
...
749  processX     0.0  **00:20.97** 4     2    46    2868K  0B     0B     749 1
...
```

I am interested in creating reports such as:

```
Top 5 Users

User   Command   #TimesRun  AverageDuration (hh:mm:ss.x)        
User A processX     2         00:00:10.5 
...
```

I know I can get the calculations once I can convert the original string into time which I can parse for the math using helpers like DATEPART. But, using things like CAST, CONVERT and even an ALTER on the original VARCHAR column are all complaining about "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time form character string"

```
ALTER TABLE TopKPIInfo ALTER COLUMN ProcTimeDur Time
SELECT CONVERT(Time, ProcTimeDur, 114) FROM TopKPIInfo
SELECT CAST(ProcTimeDur AS TIME) FROM TopKPIInfo
```

The field is a VARCHAR(8) in the system

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: You will have an enormous problem with your data and what has been proposed so far. Look closely at your sample. What exactly is "00:20.97"? 97 is what - 97/100 of a minute? And the time datatype may not be useful here if you are not careful. The domain of time has an upper bound that is less than 24 hours. Is that a concern? Do your data analysis before you start making assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that you can't alter the column data type directly - the data in it isn't compatible with a `TIME`, which means it needs to *first* be converted.

You cannot both convert and change the column type at the same time - that's not possible - what you have stored `VARCHAR(8)` isn't directly meaningful as a `TIME`, which is why the change of column type fails (SQL Server doesn't know how to do the conversion - and you can't specify the rules when trying to change the column type).

What you can do is a multi-step conversion:

1. Create a new column (say `temp_ProcTimeDur`) with type `TIME`.
2. Ensure `ProcTimeDur` is in a format that is compatible with the built in conversions - by updating the column to replace the `.` with `:`.
3. Populate this column with the correct data:

   ```
   UPDATE TopKPIInfo 
   SET temp_ProcTimeDur = CONVERT(Time, ProcTimeDur, 114)
   ```
4. Delete `ProcTimeDur`.
5. Rename `temp_ProcTimeDur` to `ProcTimeDur`.

Comment: DigiFriend, This makes sense, but I'm still getting the same error, even with a new column of the proper type. The Update statement doesn't complete unfortunately.

Comment: Make sure you are using a correct convert function - I have copied that from your code, which may be incorrect. Try to `SELECT CONVERT(Time, ProcTimeDur, 114) FROM TopKPIInfo` but with different CAST/CONVERTs - till you find one that works correctly.

Comment: `114` is not correct as it expects `hh:mm:ss:mmm`, not `hh:mm:ss.mmm` (note the last separator - yours is a `.`, `114` expects a `:`. You can get around that by replacing the `.` with a `:` before converting.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a cheap example of the comment posted earlier. I chose to convert to a minute-based value since that is what your original data appears to be. And I made assumptions - which may or may not be valid depending on the quality of your table. If needed, you could define this logic as a view, but only if the values stored in your time column are consistently and correctly formatted.

```
with cte as (select * from (values ('00:00.04'), ('00:20.97'), ('01:59.00'), ('25:01.55')) as samp(tm)),
samples as (select tm, left(tm,2) as hh, SUBSTRING(tm,4, 2) as mm, right(tm,3) as sx from cte)
select *, 
cast(hh as float) * 60 as hr_inmin, cast(mm as float) as mm_inmin, cast(sx as float) as ss_inmin, 
(cast(hh as float) * 60) + cast(mm as float) + cast(sx as float) as usabletime_minutes 
from samples
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DatetimefromParts to get this as below:

```
select [user], [command], [TimesRun] = count(*), AverageDuration = avg(TimeDetails)
from (
    select [TimeDetails] = convert(time, DATETIME2FROMPARTS(1900,1,1,
        isnull(convert(int,PARSENAME(replace(timesrun, ':','.'),4)) ,0),
        isnull(convert(int,PARSENAME(replace(timesrun, ':','.'),3)) ,0),
        isnull(convert(int,PARSENAME(replace(timesrun, ':','.'),2)) ,0),
        isnull(convert(int,PARSENAME(replace(timesrun, ':','.'),1)) ,0),
        7)), * from #yourtime 
) a
group by a.[user], a.[command]
```